# How do I disable the touchpad in elementary OS?

Tags: release-loki, touchpad

I have tried everything to disable the touchpad on my Dell laptop. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You ca disable your touchpad using your keys on your keyboard if you have (for example on mine laptop: Fn + F4) or follow this instructions on the link bellow: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/65951/how-to-disable-the-touchpad